# How to get component state within child within slot Vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3, vue-composition-api

I have a problem I can't figure out the solution 
Would like to hear your ideas about this problem.

I created reusable Form and InputField components.
The InputField component getting validation prop, a function that returns true or error message whether the input is valid or not

```
// InputField.vue
const validate = () => {
  isValid.value = props.validation(inputValue.value);
};

// App.vue
<InputField
  v-model="formData.firstName"
  element="input"
  required
  name="First Name"
  :validation="(val) => /^.{2,}$/.test(val) || 'Minimum 2 characters'"
/>
```

Now in the Form.vue, I have a variable called isValid, and if it's false, the submit function should not work.

So the problem is: How do I check the states of all the InputFields within the Form component(it receives them as a slot) to understand if isValid = true for input, (then to check if all of them are true, which is simple)

Now I'm looking for an efficient way to do that, and to make sure that it will work for multiple forms and inputs if I have it in a different place in the app, I'm not looking for a quick hack

Here is the link to the application: https://codesandbox.io/s/muddy-sun-0ti9m
You can take a look to understand exactly what I'm talking about :)

I will recap:
The main goal is to check if all inputs are valid by the validation function that had passed to them, and if the Form is not valid it will not be able to submit.

Thanks all!

Comment: Have you considered using a third party library? This one is really good, I created a whole form framework with it: https://vee-validate.logaretm.com/v4/

Comment: Thanks, I will take a look

Comment: Thanks, I adopted vee validate, a great tool!

Answer (score 0):

I´ve did some changes to your provided code, you can watch the changes in this [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/gallant-rgb-5vfqz?file=/src/App.vue). What I did was to let your `InputFields` to emit something like a unique id, `First Name`s unique id is like `firstname` in my example, and also their status of validation. The function is called `checkValidation` and the emit is addded to their implementation with `@check-validation="checkValidation"`.

There is a new object, which handles multiple status of validation. You can create it dynamically in the future, if you want to make this attemp generic. The object is:

```
const formValidationObject = reactive({
   firstname: false,
   lastname: false
});
```

The `checkValidation`  looks like this:

```
const checkValidation = (object) => {
   formValidationObject[object.data.id] = object.data.valid === true;
};
```

It´s a simple thing. The `object` passed with the emit contains the `id`, like "firstname", and the status of validation. The `formValidationObject` with it´s key will be true if `object.data.valid` is true, if not, it´s false.

Now you could do something like passing this as a prop to your `Form.vue` and handle, if anything isn´t validated.

Comment: Hi thanks for your suggestion, but I'm looking to simplify the code.
Your way is nice, but it requires to add too much code. and it's not done yet. in your way, we also need to share the state with Form.vue because the submit function happens there.

Comment: @Asaf I´m wondering if you understand, that `vue.js` already simplyfies, what would be necessary in plain `Javascript`. There are only two approaches to manage states in multiple components: 1. A store, like `vuex` or 2. Props.